# C++ program won't print to cout in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, output

I've never had trouble before, but my current C++/Xcode (7.0.1 on El Capitan) project refuses to print anything to cout (or cerr)--even a simple "Hello" (with endl) as the first line in the main program.

The debugger indicates that the program is running, it's just not outputting anything. It compiles and builds with no errors.

I tried creating a new "Hello, world" project and it works, and all my old projects work, so what could explain this one's failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the activate Console command: Cmd+Shift+C or in the menu: View, Debug Area, Activate Console.